# repeat header and footer using printThis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printthis

I would like to print large html content with header and footer repeat in all pages without overlapping using printThis.js plugin.

But header and footer is not repeating.

```js
       
        $("#printKitten").click(function () {
            $("#divContent").printThis({                
                header: $('#divHeader').html,
                footer: $('#divFooter').html
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/printThis.js"></script>



    <button id="printKitten">Print</button>
    <div id="divHeader">
        HEADER <br />HEADER <br />HEADER <br />HEADER <br />HEADER <br />HEADER <br />
    </div>
    <div id="divContent">
        <p>Content placeholder START...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...</p>
        <p>Content placeholder ...END</p>

    </div>
    <div id="divFooter">
        footer <br />footer <br />footer <br />footer <br />footer <br />footer <br />
    </div>
```

I tried with `@media print` also but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

[`printThis`](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) doesn't seem to have this feature.

You could request it.

In the meantime, you may want to consider [this approach](http://www.jessicaschillinger.us/2017/blog/print-repeating-header-browser/), using CSS. It makes use of a `table` element, where its `thead` and `tfoot` repeats, but its `tbody` doesn't repeat.

Quoting the **basic setup**:

```
<table class="report-container">
  <thead class="report-header"> </thead>
  <tfoot class="report-footer"> </tfoot>
  <tbody class="report-content"> </tbody>
</table>
```

Important notes according to author:

> - Every `<th>` must live inside a `<tr>` to work
> - `<thead>` must appear first in your `<table>`
> - You can really have whatever you want appear in the `<div class="header-info">` within the `<th>`, including other tables.  It’s like it’s 1996 again!
> - **! Very Important! `<tfoot>` must be after `<thead>` but before `tbody>`, even though it renders after `<tbody>`.**

**Main content**

```
<tbody class="report-content"> 
   <tr> 
      <td>
        <div class="main">
            ...
        </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**

```
thead.report-header {
   display: table-header-group;
}

tfoot.report-footer {
   display:table-footer-group;
}

tabel.report-container {
    page-break-after: always;
}
```

Go check that article. It's very well explained and may server as a great workaround.

Comment: Hi, I followed this approach and working fine with Chrome and FF but it always print in Report #2 format, i want in Report #1. I could not find where to update in the code for this. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: That would be another question. Please post a different one specifically for that. Be sure to provide some code so that whoever answers can reproduce your behavior

Comment: As advised, posted a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908394/how-to-print-a-repeating-header-from-the-browser